# What to look for when opening a brokerage account for a beginner?

Tags: australia, brokerage

I am John and I am 18 years old. I am looking to open a brokerage account in Australia. My question is what characteristics should I look for when opening a brokerage account as a beginner?

Comment: Always go with the "biggest, most well known" name.  If it was a car, **Toyota and forget everything else**.  DON'T EVER (anywhere in the world) use "robinhood" or other novelty brokers.  It's a straight "reliability is everything" choice. (If you're an expert and have arcane needs, you wouldn't be asking this question.)

Comment: @Fattie Hello, thanks for the advice. I want to open an account with interactive brokers but I am not wealthy enough to  meet their net worth requirements. What do you recommend based on your experience?

Answer (score 4):

Brokers offer many features but each broker doesn't offer all of them. I think that a beginner would look for basic needs first:

- Low/no commissions
- No hidden account fees
- Good customer service including tech support
- A stable platform with few service outages
- Educational resources
- Good charting
- Prompt execution and prompt account updating

A more experienced investor/trader might be interested in:

- Fractional shares
- Low margin rates
- Portfolio margin
- Good option analytics
- Trading algorithms beyond basic stop orders
- Real time news
- Effective at borrowing shares for shorting
- Stock screeners
- Free dividend re-investment

Comment: Hi Mr Baerker, thanks for your answer! Can I ask what brokerage are you using?

Comment: I use Interactive Brokers.  It's a trader's platform.  Here's an article discussing [Best Online Brokers](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/investing/best-online-brokers/).  You can google for others like this.

Comment: If the OP is looking for an Australian brokerage firm, the OP should ensure that the broker is licensed by the Australian Securities and Investments Commission (ASIC). https://moneysmart.gov.au/check-asic-lists

Comment: @Flux Hello Flux thanks for the info. I am looking for any broker/trading platform not necessarily based on Australia

Answer (score 0):

To find a broker, check out your bank's web page, see if they provide brokerage services for you to Buy/Sell.

As well as hear, look for forums which specialize at covering the ASX.com.au
eg: hotcopper.com.au

.